# Apply a function on a value array using unique elements from another

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

Let's say I have two arrays with the same dimensions: an index array `idx` and a value array `val`:

```
import numpy as np

idx = np.array([[10, 10, 13],
                [13, 10, 18],
                [10, 16, 18]])

np.random.seed(42)
val = np.round(np.random.uniform(0, 100, 9).reshape((3, 3)), 1)

print(repr(val))
# array([[30.5,  9.8, 68.4],
#        [44. , 12.2, 49.5],
#        [ 3.4, 90.9, 25.9]])
```

How can I efficiently apply a function, i.e. `mean` on the value array using the unique selections from the index array?

Here is my best brute attempt with a `for`-loop with the expected result:

```
{i: val[idx == i].mean() for i in np.unique(idx)}
# {10: 13.975, 13: 56.2, 16: 90.9, 18: 37.7}
```

While this looks fine in this example, it takes over 40 seconds in a real-world case with 6000 unique indices on an array with over 5M elements. That's too long, and I'm looking for a more efficient method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For large arrays, you should find Pandas more efficient, even after accounting for dataframe-setup and series-to-dictionary conversion costs:

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
# Python 3.7.0, Pandas 0.23.4, NumPy 1.15.1

np.random.seed(0)
n = 10**3
idx = np.random.randint(0, 20, (n, n))
val = np.random.random((n, n))

df = pd.DataFrame({'idx': idx.ravel(), 'val': val.ravel()})

%timeit pd.DataFrame({'idx': idx.ravel(), 'val': val.ravel()})  # 7.84 ms
%timeit df.groupby('idx')['val'].mean()                         # 34.6 ms
%timeit df.groupby('idx')['val'].mean().to_dict()               # 35.4 ms
%timeit {i: val[idx == i].mean() for i in np.unique(idx)}       # 108 ms
```

Comment: In my real-world case, panda's groupby methods have a 200× efficiency improvement!